# How to use images for skins without embedding them in the external style sheet

Tags: css, apache-flex, runtime, flash

I'm trying to create a run time css-based swf which **DOES NOT** have embedded images, but rather picks them up from the file system.

For example,my Current .css file has this piece of code:

```
.paySeatBundleAvailable {
    upSkin: Embed("../images/common/pay_seat_bundle_available.gif");
    overSkin: Embed("../images/common/pay_seat_bundle_available.gif");
    downSkin: Embed("../images/common/pay_seat_bundle_available.gif");  
}
```

I dont want the CSS based SWF to have all the images embedded as I have a lot of images. Rather I want the images to be loaded at runtime from the path specified.

I tried using **'Url'** in place of **'Embed'** , but it throws **'error #1034 type coercion'** error.

Help Please!! What is the correct approach?

Comment: This is not about embedded programming. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded/info. Retagged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a general skin that does all states (up, over, down, etc) which only has one Image Object.  Set the source of that Image object to the appropriate strings and the Image will then do an http call to that image automatically without embedding anything.

Comment: Hey Ian, thnks for your answer. It would be great if you could give me an example of how to implement is using external css, as per my code in the question.

Comment: Also, this would mean i need a create one skin class per image. Is it possible to have only one Actionscript/mxml file to handle all image requests for skinning different elements in my css?

Comment: Are you using Flex 3 or Flex 4?

Comment: Look at [this tutorial](http://www.asfusion.com/blog/entry/stateful-skins-in-flex-3e-color-transitions-in-buttons-now-possible) on how to create stateful skins in Flex 3 and use the same approach except for your images, do a `getStyle(this.currentState+'Image')` which will return the css for your state image so long as you specify `downImage`, `upImage`, etc in your css to just a string to the image url.